# Passing props to nested route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following routes in my VueJS app:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: PlacesList
  },
  {
    name: 'place',
    path: '/places/:name',
    component: CurrentWeather,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'alerts',
        path: 'alerts',
        component: ForecastAlerts
      },
      {
        name: 'forecast',
        path: 'forecast',
        component: ForecastTimeline
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

`ForecastTimeline` receives props passed from `CurrentWeather`:

```
export default {
  name: 'ForecastTimeline',
  props: ['forecastData'],
  components: {
    ForecastDay
  }
}
```

When I navigate to `/places/:name/forecast` from `/places/:name` everything works well. However, when I try to reach `/places/:name/forecast` directly I get a `Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined` error. This occurs because `forecastData` is fetched asynchronously within the `CurrentWeather` component. What is the proper way to handle asynchronous properties passed to a nested route?

Comment: Have you tried moving the prop definition to a mixin? that way you can include it as part of `ForcastAlerts` and `ForcastTimeline` from the same source. Another option I can think of is using a Vuex store to make the data accessable across components.

Comment: I have not tried a mixin yet. Vuex is something I plan on adding in the future, but wanted to figure out how to accomplish this without it as well.

Comment: Best other way I can think would be to have the ForcastTimeline component define an event on a global message pump so it can be called regardless of what retrieves the data

Comment: You can try adding beforeRouteEnter() in your ForecastTimeline component and check if the async task is finished, then only the data is accessible

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not displaying the subroutes components while fetching the data ?

Something like :

```
export default {
  name: 'CurrentWeather',
  data(){
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.fetchForecastData().then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    fetchForecastData() {
      return fetch('http://..');
    }
  }
}
```

In CurrentWeather template :

```
<router-view v-if="!loading"></router-view>
```